# Memory Error during string replacement in python

Tags: python

I wanted to answer a rather easy looking question on stackoverflow.
Original code (not mine):

```py
def to_alternating_case(string):
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) in range(97, 123):
            string.replace(char, string.upper())
        elif ord(char) in range (65,91):
            string.replace(char, string.lower())
        elif ord(char) in range (32, 48):
            continue
        else:
            return '//Non-alphabetical characters are unaffected'
    return string
```

Of course, because strings are immutable and `string.replace` cannot change the original string, the return value is still the original string (lower and upper case should have been swapped by the intention of the original programmer). So I wanted to suggest the following simple fix:

```py
def to_alternating_case(string):
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) in range(97, 123):
            string = string.replace(char, string.upper())
        elif ord(char) in range (65,91):
            string = string.replace(char, string.lower())
        elif ord(char) in range (32, 48):
            continue
        else:
            return '//Non-alphabetical characters are unaffected'
    return string


print(to_alternating_case("Guten Tag"))
```

But instead of new hard earned reputation points and a warm 'thank you' I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(to_alternating_case("Guten Tag"))
  File "main.py", line 4, in to_alternating_case
    string = string.replace(char, string.upper())
MemoryError
```

At the moment I am truly puzzled. What is going on? I did not check the numbers, so I currently would expect any string - but not a MemoryError.

*Disclaimer:* Yes, I know the original issue can be solved with the one-liner `to_alternating_case = lambda s: ''.join(c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in s)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should possibly rethink this:

```
string = string.replace(char, string.upper())
```

This replaces the character with an upper-case version of the entire *string,* probably not what you wanted. It's going to get very big, very fast, and possibly run out of memory. One would hope Python would raise a signal of some description should that occur :-)

---

And, just as an aside, you should be very circumspect about the possibility of modifying things that you're currently iterating over, that tends to lead to either double-processing of items, or missing of items, the classic case being:

```
for item in someList:
    if item < 0:
        someList.remove(item)
```

That's not *actually* the case in your code since you're simply rebinding `string` to a new object *after* you've started iterating over the thing it originally pointed to, but it's still a good habit to avoid in case it gives you a false sense of security.

In those cases (where it matters), it's better to create a *new* item and then, once built assign back to the original somehow.

Comment: This was more fun than I expected. Thank you both very much.

Comment: Thank you, @juanpa.arrivillaga, that was a bad call on my part. I've updated the answer to make that clear, leaving it in because success with this sort of stuff may lead to a presumption it will work in the problematic cases.